# jQuery: Looping over elements writing their ID attribute to an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, loops, matching

I'm trying find a bunch of `<label>s` in a form of mine based on an array of elements and their id attribute.

**eg**. `[ input#country , input#other-country ]` would be able to find `<label for="country"> , <label for="other-country">` and so on…

so far I have this code:

```
var LOCATION = {};

LOCATION.option = form.find('input[name=location]').toArray();
LOCATION.labels = [
    $.each( LOCATION.option, function(i, input) {
        $('label[for='+input.id+']');
    })
];
```

When logging out the `input.id` inside the `$.each` loop I get the correct value being written out however I can't seem to find a way to write my matched `label` element from inside the `$.each` loop into the `LOCATION.labels` array afterwards.

Does anyone know how to put them into the array? `toArray()` does not seem to work either…

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map):

```
var LOCATION = {};

LOCATION.option = form.find('input[name=location]').toArray();
LOCATION.labels = $.map( LOCATION.option, function(input) {
  return $('label[for='+input.id+']').get(0);
});
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SyFPF/) for an example of this in action.

Comment: Ah, hadn't refreshed the page before posting my Fiddle… many thanks! This works wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out. Not really a one line solution to get directly the array, but I've tested this and it works fine.

```
var LOCATION = {};
$(function(){
  var form = $("#form"); //sample form
  LOCATION.option = form.find('input[name=location]').toArray();
  LOCATION.labels = [];
  $.each(LOCATION.option, function(i,input) {        
    LOCATION.labels.push($('label[for='+input.id+']').get(0));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I am using the once Dave gave me for this project but it's good to know that .push will work equally well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, just `.push()` from inside `.each()`

```
var LOCATION = {};

LOCATION.option = form.find('input[name=location]').toArray();
LOCATION.labels = [];

$.each( LOCATION.option, function(i, input) {
    LOCATION.labels.push($('label[for='+input.id+']'));
})
```